# Shell-script-internal encoding differs from redirected output

Tags: bash, ubuntu, character-encoding

Currently I'm dealing with a bunch of old files that have seen a lot of machines, OSes and file systems during their lifetime. A couple of them contain german Umlauts (ä, ö, ü), and apparently these have caused some of the filenames to break in one of the moving processes. A file originally named

```
München.txt
```

appears as

```
M?nchen.txt (invalid encoding)
```

on the ubuntu system, where they are currently hosted.

So now I'm trying to bulk repair them. On looping through the files with the initial draft, I stumbled across this phenomenon:

- Echoing to the screen gives me the filename with the question mark, which I understand is a sign of interpretation of an illegal character within the filename:

  ```
   ./list_files.sh path_to_files

   M?nchen.txt
   K?ln.txt
  ```
- If however I save the output to a file, it will give me a binary file that still contains the invalid characters:

  ```
   ./list_files.sh path_to_files > file_list

   less file_list
   M<FC>nchen.txt
   K<F6>ln.txt
  ```

This is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash

rootdir=$1

find "$rootdir" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' broken_file_name; do
    echo $broken_file_name
done
```

I'm trying to understand:

1. Why is the screen output different from the one in the file? Where does the character replacement happen and where is the question-mark-thing created?
2. How can I prevent the interpretation of illegal characters with the question-mark-thing within the process of the script? It prevents me from selectively replacing an illegal character with the corresponding correct one.

Comment: The different behavior with `less` is probably a `less` thing. From the manual: "_Otherwise, the character is displayed  as a hex number in angle brackets.  This format can be changed by setting the LESSBINFMT environment variable._" (the _Otherwise_ is for binary characters that are not control characters). While with `echo`, `printf`, `cat`... unprintable characters are shown as `?`.

Comment: Are the question marks still there for `./list_files.sh path_to_files | cat`? If so, they may be printed by the terminal for an unrecognised byte. If _not_, I would guess that `iconv` is being used, but only if stdout is a terminal (it prints `?` for unrecognised). The bytes `\xFC` and `\xF6` are not valid ASCII or UTF-8, as they are between 128-255 (in base 10). `less` prints binary byte `\xF6` like `<F6>`. You can use `hexdump` (or `hd`) for a clearer view. Also look at `iconv` and its `//TRANSLIT` flag, for help converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark replacement probably happens in Bash itself, as long as you are using Bash `echo` and try to output characters which cannot be represented in the current locale. It could also be a feature of the terminal driver.

We can only speculate about the original encoding, but the symptoms are consistent with Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1).

Assuming I guessed the encoding correctly, and assuming your current locale is a UTF-8 one, try something like

```sh
while IFS= read -r original; do
    dest=$(iconv -f iso-8859-1 <<<"$original")
    mv -- "$original" "$dest"
done <file_list
```

Comment: If Latin-1 was not a correct guess and you have more samples to infer from, maybe look them up at https://tripleee.github.io/8bit/

Comment: Do you think `iconv`'s `//TRANSLIT` flag would be helpful with this character set?

Comment: @dan I don't understand why you would want that. The destination character set is (presumably) UTF-8 so there should be no characters in the original character set which cannot be represented.

Comment: Ok cool. I was thinking there might be some obscure characters with no equivalent, but I guess umlauts are covered.

Comment: Not only that; Latin-1 has the curious property that its code points are identical to Unicode in the 8-bit range.

Comment: @tripleee: That actually solves the problem - thx! It also takes care of some more rogue characters like "ß" and French accents. As for the original encoding, I did some reading and learned that Latin apparently is the base for some windows code pages. There is a high probability that the files have originated on a windows machine, so I assume that the original encoding was one of those.

Comment: Windows code page 1252 is the usual suspect in those circumstances. It is quite similar to Latin-1.

Answer (score 0):

The different behavior with `less` is probably a `less` thing. From the manual:

> Control  and binary characters are displayed in standout (reverse video). Each such character is displayed in caret notation if possible (e.g. ^A for control-A). Caret notation is used only if inverting the 0100 bit results in a normal printable character. Otherwise, the character is displayed as a hex number in angle brackets. This format can be changed by setting the LESSBINFMT environment variable.

But as what you want is rename your files, the way the names are displayed by various utilities is not that important. In your script you can use, e.g., `tr` to compute the new name by replacing the characters you do not like by others. Example if you want to replace ö and ü by o and u, respectively:

```sh
new=$(tr '\366\374' 'ou' <<< "$old")
if [ "$new" != "$old" ]; then
  mv "$old" "$new"
fi
```

(366 and 374 are the ascii codes of ö and ü, in octal).

Comment: This will drop the accents rather than actually try to fix them.

Comment: Yes. I thought it was what the OP want. Am I wrong?

Comment: I would assume they want the original character back.

Comment: Oh, and 366 and 374 are not ASCII codes at all, the range of ASCII ends at octal 177. The character codes you have are valid in Latin-1 and some other 8-bit encodings.

Comment: Oh, I got it, thanks! It was a character encoding issue. Let's wait until the OP confirms and I'll delete my answer. Suggestion: you could copy-paste my explanation why `less` behaves differently in your own answer, for completeness.

Comment: I'd say leave it, in case future visitors have a similar but different problem.

Comment: OK, let's do that.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: tripleee is right, my original intention was to replace the invalid characters with their corresponding correct representation of the original ones. Thanks though!